# Cardinity payment error MethodNotAllowed

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

Can anybody help me to solve this error.

**My code:**

```
$method = new Finalize(Session::get($request['MD']), $request['PaRes']);
```

**Error:**

> Method Not Allowed – You tried to access a resource using an invalid HTTP method. Response data: C:22:"Cardinity\Method\Error":174:{{"type":"https://developers.cardinity.com/api/v1/#405","title":"Method Not Allowed","status":405,"detail":"This resource supports only GET,POST, but you've sent PATCH."}}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $request['MD'] value is not empty, because with PATCH/PUT requests you must specify which entity you are updating.